# Pipe infinite output from shell command to a python script

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, unix, pipe

I would like to forward the output from one script to the another.

I try to do it like that:

```
./producer.py > ./consumer.py
```

Where procuder:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys
import time

i=0
while True:
    print(i)
    i+=1
    time.sleep(1)
```

And consumer:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import sys

f= open("test.txt","w+")

while True:
    line = sys.stdin.read()
    print(line)
    f.write(line)
```

I expect that producer will generate: 1 2 3 4 5 and this pipe will be saved in file test.txt by another script. Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1):

Use a pipe `|` instead of `>` to forward output (stdout) from one process to another (as stdin). Also, beware that the data over the pipe is buffered, which may seem like nothing is happening when there is not a lot of data and the stream is never closed.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a queue with two threads instead.  [Here](https://www.troyfawkes.com/learn-python-multithreading-queues-basics/) is a good basic guide.  [Here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_multithreading.htm) is another guide.

Answer (score 0):

Try using **subprocess** and then save the data from output pipe to file. You do not need to execute the command outside.

```
from subprocess import PIPE,Popen

process = Popen(['python','test.py'],stderr=PIPE,stdout=PIPE)

output = process.stdout.readlines()
```